# Проверка checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Добрый день! Хочу подвесить обработчик на checkbox, для этого решил проверить его состояние при клике на checkbox, т.е. поставил пользователь галочку - запустился скрипт, снял - не запустилось ничего. Пишу:

```
$("#ELEMENT_ID").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Хоть нажат checkbox, хоть нет - всёравно в консоле вижу "**on**". Как такую проверку сделать? К слову

```
console.log($(this).attr("checked"));
```

возвращает всегда вначале "**on**" а потом пишет "**undefined**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте функцию is, она возвращает true если чекбокс отмечен и false в противном случае:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/L30rq5pm/)

Comment: Стоит также пояснить, почему автор вопроса столкнулся с таким поведением. Атрибут [`checked`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) по спецификации HTML не имеет значения (в XHTML должен обязательно иметь значение "checked"). Если атрибут присутствует в `input[type=checkbox]`'е, он будет считаться отмеченным [вне зависимости от значения этого атрибута](http://jsfiddle.net/jzgoxhaq/). Поэтому для отмеченных checkbox'ов атрибут будет иметь какое-нибудь значение (например, "on"), а для не отмеченных он будет отсутствовать (отсюда значение `undefined`).

Comment: Работает как часики! Спасибо!

Answer (score -3):

для проверки юзай

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Не вводите человека в заблуждение. Предложенные вами строки не _проверяют_, а _устанавливают_ значение checkbox.